# celery workers don't receive broadcast tasks

Tags: python, celery

I have a simple celery + django setup which works fine until I change the `Queue` to `Broadcast`, instead of all the workers get the task, None of them do.

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from kombu.common import Broadcast
from billiard import current_process
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'celery_tutorial.settings')

app = Celery('celery_tutorial')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
# exchange = Exchange('custom_exchange', type='fanout')
# app.conf.task_queues = (Broadcast('broadcast_tasks'),)
app.conf.task_queues = (Queue('broadcast_tasks'),)

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.task_routes = {
    'tasks.debug_task': {
        'queue': 'broadcast_tasks',
        'exchange': 'broadcast_tasks'
    }
}

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'worker id: {current_process().index}')
```

Now when I submit a task it works fine:

```python
from celery_tutorial.celery import debug_task

debug_task.apply_async(queue='broadcast_tasks')
```

Worker logs:

> [2020-10-31 16:44:50,770: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] worker id: 1

If I change the `Queue` to `Broadcast` nothing will appear on workers logs.

(I run workers with `celery -A celery_tutorial.celery worker -c 2 -Q broadcast_tasks`)

PS: I switched redis to amqp and now one of the workers gets the task but not the second.

Comment: can you show your celery settings from the settings.py module? Also consider running the workers with debug logging enabled and report the output.

Comment: @sytech workers logs are empty even with log level at debug. Seems like they don't get notified about the task at all.

Comment: Your settings are important here. You need to have the proper queues configured or you'd expect to see this behavior.

Comment: @sytech there is only `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in  `settings.py` that is related to celery.

Comment: As-is, I believe your routing settings are improper. See: [Broadcast](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#broadcast). `app.autodiscover_tasks` should also come after all configurations.

Comment: @sytech Thet's exactly where I took my settings from. Moving `app.autodiscover_tasks` to the end of config didn't help.

Comment: `app.conf.task_queues = (Broadcast('broadcast_tasks'),)` is in the docs. That's not what you have, it seems. Unless I'm missing something, sorry.

Comment: Also to confirm: you're using an AMQP backend, right? (non AMQP backends like redis and SQS don't support exchanges)

Comment: @sytech I switched to amqp and now the task is done but only once instead of twice, once by each worker.